# I want to find the factorial of a number using a default and parameterize constructor. getting output as 0

Tags: java

I have declared a default and a parameterize constructor. Using a single object I am calling both the constructor and an function. When I run the program I am getting the output as 0 instead of getting the factorial. I have initialize f=1 still the output is 0.

```
class Factorial
{
    int num, f;

    Factorial()
    {
        f = 1;
    }

    Factorial(int n)
    {
        num = n;
    }

    public int getFactorial()
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
        }   
        System.out.println("Factorial= " + f);
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(int m)
    {     
        Factorial obj = new Factorial();
        obj = new Factorial(m);
        obj.getFactorial();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: class names in Java start UpperCase. And don't abbreviate variable names. Instead: use names that tell something about the thing behind the name!

Answer (score 3):

This is because the initial value of `f` remains zero when the class is initialized with the `factorial(int n)` constructor.

Set `f` to `1` in the initializer to fix this problem:

```
int n, f = 1;

Factorial() {
}

Factorial(int n) {
    num = n;
}
```

This leaves your class with a big problem: calling `getfactorial` multiple times will change the state of the class, increasing the value of the factorial. You can fix this by creating a `boolean` variable that indicates whether the factorial has been computed or not, and returning `f` after the computation has been performed.

If you do not need "lazy" computation, make `f` a local variable in the method.

Comment: Well ... even better: Make `f` a method local variable!

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The problem with that approach is that the factorial is recomputed each time `getfactorial` is called, making the class nearly pointless. Current design, on the other hand, lets OP compute factorial lazily, as a matter of exercise.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I have edited the answer before posting my previous comment to explain that point.

Comment: I am sorry. Obviously I overlooked some of your sentences. I should stop commenting this evening.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, a variable should have the minimal possible scope (preferred local, then instance). Or in other words: state variables should be used just when you want to share some date between several methods of the same class. But what in your case? Factorial is an operation that may be computed in just one step, from one single parameter: No need to further processing.

So, I recommend you to refactorize your class to:

1. Drop off the state variables: Convert them to local variables or parameters to the method.
2. Set the factorial method as static (precisely because it does not need state variables).
3. Another small detail: Parameters are passed from command line to the `main` method through an array of Strings - always.
4. Leave all the inputs and outputs to/from the user in just one method, preferrably the `main` method.

So it will remain like this:

```
class Factorial
{
    public static int getFactorial(int num)
    {
        int f=1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
        {
            f = f * i;
        }   
        return f;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {     
        int m=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int factorial=Factorial.getFactorial(m);
        System.out.printf("factorial of %d is %d\n", m, factorial);
    }
}
```

Much simplier, isn't it?